# Browser not responding to the changes made to my code

Tags: html, css, web, browser

So I'm working on this web project for school and I use atom as editor and both chrome and opera as my browsers to view my work.
The problem is after few time refreshing the page to view my changes the browser does not respond and keep giving me the same old styling or contents I had on the page, I even had a registration form and every time I refresh it the page goes blank and I need to refresh it again in order to see it and when using chrome to view this same page, a confirmation dialogue pops up, I don't know what the problem is and I was wondering if someone can help me figuring it out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your webpage might be cached maybe?

Comment: You can try CTRL + F5 to clear the cache.

Comment: i did clear the cache but still the same

Comment: Can you please open your dev tools in Chrome and see if there are any console errors? While you in there make sure disable cache when dev tools is open checked on

Comment: i have no errors loged to console because i'm not using any script just html and css

Comment: What does your environment look like? Windows, mac, linux? What node version is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you save your file it auto refresh the page and shows the changed
[Atom live server](https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server)

Comment: only html and css in most pages, only included 1 line of js in another page. i wanted to be done with the markup before going through the scripting

Comment: yeah i'm actually using that for the moment thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

open your web page in browser and reload by this Shift + Ctrl + R

It will refresh the whole page and show like first time opening.

(or)

check in private window of your browser...

You can see the css is reflected

Comment: i did clear the history before but thats not very effective since i need alot of the informations thats gonna be removed. i'll try the private window tho.

Comment: i meant information about my browsing history and the code is over 1500 lines so far i don't think it fits in this comment

Answer (score 0):

If its a browser issue: Try Uninstalling and reinstalling chrome.

Check to make sure your looking at the right directory, many developers including myself make the mistake of looking at the wrong code base.

Comment: if you mean looking at the project i have the path bookmarked since day one. thanks tho i did this one before and it drove me mad xD

Comment: Another silly question: Have you tried shutting the dev server down and reloading it?

Comment: by dev server you mean xampp ?

Comment: If xampp is hosting your website on your local machine then yes. If Atom creating a localhost:xxxx then restart the server through atom.

Comment: no actually for the moment is neither of them because i'm working with just html and css didn't need to use xampp

Comment: ok so your loading the file directly from a path on your os? try moving the file and hitting the page again to see if it still works. If it works then xampp may still be running without you knowing it.  This would mean that your likely loading the file from a cached location.

Comment: oh, didn't know that, and how do i keep him from caching my files location ?